# My NGINX configuration is now throwing 404 Not Found nginx/1.10.0 (Ubuntu)

Tags: php, mysql, magento, nginx

I'm going to try and make this as detailed as possible because I feel like I've tried everything and at this point just need another set of eyes on everything.

I'm running a cloud server and I've installed my LEMP stack via terminal. Additionally, this is a magento build. I've migrated all files to the proper folder. var/www/html and I've installed mysql and imported my DB.

I'm currently able to run mywebsite.com/info.php

```
tki@me:/$ sudo nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
tki@me:/$ ls -al /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Feb  6 18:44 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Feb  6 18:03 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   34 Feb  4 15:48 default -> /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
tki@me:/$ sudo lsof -i -P | grep -i "listen"
sendmail-  1084               root    3u  IPv4  14208      0t0  TCP localhost:25 (LISTEN)
sendmail-  1084               root    5u  IPv4  14209      0t0  TCP localhost:587 (LISTEN)
sshd       1122               root    3u  IPv4  14322      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
sshd       1122               root    4u  IPv6  14331      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
mysqld    14732              mysql   19u  IPv4  76527      0t0  TCP localhost:3306 (LISTEN)
```

Here is my sites-available/default

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;   

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    #index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    #server_name server_domain_or_IP;
     server_name mysite.com;
    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Here is my sites-enabled/default

```
    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/html;
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;   

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        #index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        #server_name server_domain_or_IP;
         server_name mysite.com;
        location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            }


        location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
        }
    }

Here is my nginx.conf file:

user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;
    # fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_CODE default;
    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;


    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;


    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";


    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Is there anything blatantly obvious that's wrong with my configurations?